# jQuery - change element height if other element becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, resize, visible

I have 3 buttons that toggleFade() 3 divs. When i click #link1, the div1 fadeIn() and so on..
My goal is to resize #map_canvas if any of these divs are faded in, and resize to default if none are visible (fadeOut()).

```
    <a id="link1"></a>
    <a id="link2"></a>
    <a id="link3"></a>

    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

    <div id="wrapper">

   <div id="div1" class="hideMe"></div>
   <div id="div2" class="hideMe"></div>
   <div id="div3" class="hideMe"></div>

   </div>
```

EDIT: jQuery of fadeIn and fadeOut.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#div1').hide();
     $('a#link1').click(function() {

 if (!$('#div1').is(':visible')) 
   {
     $('.hideMe').fadeOut("slow");
     $('#map_canvas').animate({height:"370px"}, 500);
    }

     $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow");

  });
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: yeah, add your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as much as I could understand I implemented an example.  I only did the first two buttons you can use the first two buttons as example to implement the third.

Note: Its possible to consolidate the jQuery so that there is only one click function however while learning Its helpful to keep it separated so its more understandable.

HTML

```
<a id="link1">link1</a>
<a id="link2">link2</a>
<a id="link3">link3</a>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="div1" class="hideMe">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="hideMe">div2</div>
<div id="div3" class="hideMe">div3</div>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hideMe').hide();
        $('#link1').click(function() {
          $('.hideMe').not('#div1').hide();
          $('#div1').fadeToggle("slow",function(){
              if ($('#div1').is(':visible')) 
              { 
                  $('#map_canvas').animate({height:"370px"}, 500);
              }
              if(!$('.hideMe').is(':visible')){
                  $('#map_canvas').animate({height:"0px"}, 500);
              }
          });
        });
        $('#link2').click(function() {
            $('.hideMe').not('#div2').hide();
            $('#div2').fadeToggle("slow",function(){
              if ($('#div2').is(':visible')) 
                  {
                    $('#map_canvas').animate({height:"370px"}, 500);
                  }
              if(!$('.hideMe').is(':visible')){
                  $('#map_canvas').animate({height:"0px"}, 500);
              }
            });
          });
    });
```

CSS

```
       #map_canvas {
        border: 1px solid black;
       }
       a {
           cursor:pointer;
       }
```

Fiddle can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/qYys7/